# React context is not working in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I have written context file `AuthContext.ts`.
Here is the code

```
/*-- imports, interfaces and defaults --*/

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>(contextDefaults);

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

const AuthProvider = ({ children }: AuthProviderProps) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);

  const isLoggedIn = !!user;

  const login = (data: User) => {
    setUser(data);
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setUser(null);
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, isLoggedIn, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthProvider;
```

When I write return script in above code Visual Studio Code doesn't provide AuthContext in suggestions But when I use AuthProvider then it shows errors:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the file extension to `.tsx`

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `children` of type `ReactNode`:

```
import { ReactNode } from 'react';

const AuthProvider = ({ children }: ReactNode) => { ... }
```